# Integer part of $\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the value of the following infinite series:
$$\left\lfloor\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}\right\rfloor$$

Now, my doubt is whether it's​ $2$ or it's​ $3$. I'm not sure if it just converges to $3$ but not actually reaches it or if it completely attains the value of $3$. 
I would to like to see the proof (formal) as well instead of just intuitions.

Comment: Intuition would be solving $x^3= 24 + x$. You can easily see $x=3$ is a solution

Comment: It also can't be $2$ because the whole expression has to be greater than $\sqrt[3]{24}$

Comment: @Dylan Yes, true. The method using $x=\cdots$ mentioned as answers below is known to me. And Dylan, I know that it's not equal to $2$, but rather $>2$. My question is, does it exactly reach $3$? Or the limit is $3$ but not attainable? That's my question and I'm somewhat not satisfied with the answers below. May I get a clear explanation of it? The question asks for the integer part. So, if it somewhat reached $3$ but isn't exactly $3$, then in that case, the integer part would be $2$, else $3$.

Comment: @Mathbg If it goes on forever, it will be $3$ exactly. If you stop it at a finite point, it will be less than $3$.

Comment: That depends on what sequence are you talking about, if it is $a_n = \sqrt[3]{24+a_{n-1}}$ then this indeed reaches $3$ in infinity, but if you are instead talking about $b_n = \lfloor a_n \rfloor$, then since $a_n$ is monotically increasing, this sequence limit is $2$. The notation of infinitely nested radicals is often ambiguous, you should write out the actual sequence.

Comment: @Sil Yes, exactly. I'm talking about $\lfloor a_n \rfloor_{n\to \infty}$

Comment: I guess the key part to realize here is if you are interested in limit of integer parts, or integer part of the limit itself. From what you write in comments it seems like the former. But your question (and everyone's answer so far) works with the latter. In other words
$$\lfloor \lim a_n \rfloor \neq\lim \lfloor  a_n \rfloor$$

Comment: @Sil Check the question. It's the later only. I'm talking about the GIF of the infinite series. (GIF is same as floor function)

Comment: Then the answer is simple, $\lim a_n = 3$ and therefore $\lfloor \lim a_n \rfloor = \lfloor 3 \rfloor = 3.$

Comment: The way you have written the expression in question it means that you are interested in integer part of the limit and then the answer is $3$. I don't think there is way to indicate $\lim [a_n] $ without using the limit notation.

Answer (score 5):

Define $x_0:=\sqrt[3]{24}$ and $x_n:=\sqrt[3]{24+x_{n-1}}$ for $n\geqslant 1$. This sequence generates the "infinite series" you have stated. We are interested then whether there is a limit point for $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. First notice that $x_n\leqslant 3$ for all $n\geqslant 0$. This can be proven by induction. For $n=0$ it is obvious. Suppose $x_{n-1}\leqslant 3$ then $$x_n=\sqrt[3]{24+x_{n-1}}\Leftrightarrow x_n^3=24 + x_{n-1}\leqslant 24+3=27\Rightarrow x_n\leqslant 3$$
Hence our sequence is bounded above. Clearly also bounded below by $x_0$. Thus a bounded sequence. Now we show that it is monotone (increasing in this case). 
$$x_n-x_{n-1}=x_n-x_n^3+24=(3-x_n)(x_n^2+3x_n+8)\geqslant 0$$
for all $n$. This follows since $x_n\leqslant 3$ for all $n$ and that the quadratic expression is always positive. Now we have a bounded and monotone sequence so by Bolzano-Weierstrass it must be the case that $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a limit point $x$ i.e. $\lim_nx_n=x$. So 
$$\lim_nx_n^3=\lim_n(24+x_{n-1})\Leftrightarrow x^3=24+x\Rightarrow x=3$$
Indeed the infinite series converges to $3$.

Comment: This is the answer (so far) with all the proper justification. +1

Answer (score 3):

$$x=\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$$
$$x=\sqrt[3]{24+x}$$
$$x^3=24+x$$
$$x^3-x-24=0$$
[And it's only real root is 3](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-x-24%3D0), so:
$$3=\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

If you assume that the limit exists, it is fairly easy to see that it must be $3$.  However, the existence is not entirely obvious.  To see that the limit exists:

Let $a_n$ be your expression truncated after the $n^{th}$ $24$.  Then the value you want is $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n$.

We remark that $a_n=\sqrt[3] {a_{n-1}+24}$.    As $f(x)=\sqrt[3] {x+24}$ is an increasing function we see that $a_n>a_{n-1}$.

We now claim that $a_n<3 \,\,\forall n$.

This is easily confirmed for $n=1$, as $a_1\approx 2.8845$. But if $a_n>3$ then $a_{n-1}=a_n^3-24>3$ so we are done by induction.

Since an increasing bounded sequence of real numbers must approach a limit, we deduce that $\lim_{n\to \infty} x_n$ exists.  Call it $L$.

Now our recursion tells us that $L^3=24+L$ from which it quickly follows that $L=3$.

Answer (score 2):

It is equal to $3$.

Let $x=\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$.

Then $x^3-24=x \implies x^3-x-24=(x-3)(x^2+3x+8)=0$. Thus this equation gives $x=3$ as the only real solution.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$x=\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+...}}$$ Substituing $x$ into part of the equation yields
$$x=\sqrt[3]{24+x}$$
Solving for $x$ will give you your answer.

You can do this formally by recursively defining the sequence
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{24+a_n}$$
Taking the limit as $n$ goes to infinity yields $$a_{\infty+1}=a_\infty=\sqrt[3]{24+a_\infty}$$
You use the fact that $\infty+1=\infty$ in that last line.

Comment: True but infinity isn't a particular number for a fact. Like, the value tends to reach $3$ but doesn't actually reach $3$, isn't it? In that case, the integer part is $2$. Right?

Comment: It is a part of the [Extended Real Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), but not the Real Numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ the sequence defined by$$x_n=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }n=0\\\sqrt[3]{24+x_{n-1}}&\text{ if }n\in\mathbb{N}.\end{cases}$$Then your number is $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$, if it exists. Now, let $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{24+x}$.

Note that $(\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}_+):x_n<3$. This is clear if $n=0$. Otherwise, if $x_n<3$, then $x_{n+1}<\sqrt[3]{24+3}=3$.

On the other hand, $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is an increasing sequence, because, if $0\leqslant x<3$, $f(x)>x$. This can be established observing that $f(x)=x$ if $x=3$ and that $f'(x)=\frac1{3(24+x)^{2/3}}<1$.

Since $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_+}$ is an increasing sequence and it has an upper bound, it converges to some real number $l$. And, since$$(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}):x_n=f(x_{n-1})$$and $f$ is continuous, $l=f(l)$. Now, all that remains to be done is to find the solutions of the euation $f(x)=x$. But$$f(x)=x\iff x+24=x^3,$$and this equation has one and only one real root, which is $3$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$x= \sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+...}}$$ $$x^3 = 24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+...}}$$
Notice $x^3 -24$ will be itself so $$x^3-24=x$$ Solving for $x$ yields $$3, \frac{3+\sqrt{23}i}{2}, \frac{3-\sqrt{23}i}{2}$$ but since we are concerning real solutions, 3 is the answer. It will be infinitely close to 3 amd reaches 3 so the answer is 3. ^^

Edit: That symbol is usually called "floor function".

Answer (score 1):

set

$$x =\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$$

then

$$x^3 = 24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$$

$$x^3 = 24 + x$$

Shooting for the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), consider the divisors of $24$. 2 does not satisfy the equation, clearly as $8 \neq 26$. However, $3^3 = 24 + 3$, so

$$3 =\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$$

Dividing the cubic by $x-3$ yields $x^2 + 3x + 8$ which has no real roots as $9 - 32 = -23 < 0$, so that's our only possible solution.