# Is $\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$ even? prime? composite? an even prime?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, nested-radicals

I am not being able to solve this question.  It is basically a high school level question and chapter I think is basic fundamentals of maths.

> The value of
> $$\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$$
> is equal to ...
>
> 1. an even number
> 2. a prime number
> 3. a composite number
> 4. an even prime number

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integer part of $\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\sqrt[3]{24+\cdots}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2548701/integer-part-of-sqrt324-sqrt324-sqrt324-cdots)

Comment: why should it even be an integer?

Answer (score 0):

Let us call this number X. Cubing it we have

$X^3=X+24$ so $X$ is the solution of $X^3-X-24=0$ substituting( or using Wolfram) the divisors of $24$ we have that $3$ is the only real solution.

Comment: Why should we assume there is such a number?

Comment: It is already said in the question. But if we assume that $a_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{a_n+24}$ and $a_0=\sqrt[3]{24}$. It is easy to see that it is bounded by 3 and increasing.